# How to set a Flux into a list object inside a Mono

Tags: java, spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I am new to project reactor and I am trying to set a `List<Object>` inside a `Mono<Object>` using a `Flux<Object>`.

So I have a `Mono<Person>` with an attribute called `items` which is a `List<Item>`. Then I received from my service layer a `Flux<Item>` that I nedd put in items, inside `Mono<Person>`.

Here is my code:

```
public class Person {

       List<Item> items;

}
```

```
Flux<Item> items = service.getItems();

Person person = new Person();
Mono<Person> monoPerson = Mono.just(person)
                              .map(p -> p.setItems(items))
                              ... //Here I have received an error because a required type is 
                              ... //a List<Items> and I am sendind a Flux<List>
```

I am frying my mind with this. Some help would be more than appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to think of it as a flow of operations.

What should happens is:

1. You receive a flow of items
2. You collect them as they arrive
3. Once they've all been collected, you assign them to new Person

What gives approximately:

```java
public Mono<Person> createPersonFromReceivedItems() {
    Flux<Item> items = service.getItems(); // <1>
    Mono<List<Item>> collectedItems = items.collectList(); // <2>
    Mono<Person> result = collectedItems.map( itemList -> {  // <3>
        Person p = new Person();
        p.setItems(itemList);
        return p;
    });
    
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I could not get this to work? My version of service.getItems() returns a "FluxOnErrorResume" and I never get any data.

Comment: @PlunkettBoy It's difficult to say without more details. When using onErrorResume, you might silencing an exception that would provide insight about the problem. It may also be that called service returns an empty flux, in which case something like `switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new IllegalStateException("EMPTY !")` can help detect such cases. Anyway, if you cannot find a solution, please post a question with details of your case.